# Is it possible to programmatically prevent a game from pausing when its window loses focus?

Tags: c++, directx, windows

I'm playing Skyrim in windowed mode and I am trying to create a bot for this game for personal use. I would like to have the bot play the game in the background, while I do other things, the only problem is that the game window pauses when it loses focus. Is there a way to make the Skyrim process think that it still has the focus, so it continues to run while I do something else on another window? I'm not a windows programming expert but would this be possible if I could somehow intercept the message that says unfocused or minimized to the process, and thus let the process think its still focused? I think Skyrim uses directx, so is it possible to come up with a solution from that end?

Comment: Will I help you violate the EULA by writing a bot? No. If you want the bot to play the game for you, then perhaps you should consider if the game actually interests you at all.

Comment: @DeadMG - The game doesn't interest me whatsoever, I'm creating a bot for another purpose. And is there no way to do it without violating the EULA?

Comment: Given that the EULA explicitly forbids botting, then no.

Comment: EULA's are the preference of the producer, not a binding contract. With that said, there are plenty of very useful reasons to do this. There are even contests that development companies have held for doing this exact thing.

Comment: I'm a bit confused... why is botting even relevant for a single player game? An MMORPG has a reasonable basis to deny botting, but I do not even understand the rationale behind preventing people from programming a bot for a single player game.

Comment: It's not our job to police EULAs. If you don't want to answer, that's fine, but the question seems reasonable to me.

Comment: An interesting question, I don't know the answer, but I'm curious as to what your intentions are :).

Comment: How are you sending the mouse/keyboard events to the game in the background?  I would guess that you'll need to do that too?

Comment: Duplicate on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243085/how-can-i-send-keyboard-and-mouse-input-to-a-game-that-is-not-the-active-window

Comment: @tugs - I asked the question there originally and then here, as it was suggested there that this site would be more appropriate. EDIT: I just noticed you are referring to a different question, although I asked that one too, it isn't exactly the same. This is the duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091229/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-prevent-a-game-from-pausing-when-its-window-l

Comment: You're right I grabbed the wrong browser tab...  Just wanted to make sure if anyone comes here looking for the same thing the get to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well the Eula doesn't really have any actual legal basis as long as you're not hurting anyone but yourself. And it is possible to do what you want, I don't know the specifics but basically you intercept the windows messages and have it ignore any kind of non focusing messages or just force it into thinking it's focused.